# Issue with Blazor PWA

Tags: progressive-web-apps, blazor, blazor-client-side

I am fairly new to Blazor PWA and I am creating a blazor Progressive Web Application by following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/progressive-web-app?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) link. I am in need of running my web application as a native mobile app. Therefore, I am publishing my contents in to azure for making it as a secured (https) link. Once I published my contents from `bin\Release\{TARGET_FRAMEWORK}\publish\` to azure, I am getting the below error.

`Service worker: Install`

`Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://domain/index.html' with computed SHA-256 integrity '24cvRtDoUxDkJ3HuCGqYq81Jhyp/VgpUn8C5SrxMGG4='. The resource has been blocked.`

`Unknown error occurred while trying to verify integrity.`

`service-worker.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch`

[image]

On exploring the application tab of browser, it gives me like this.

[image]

Also I tried with [pwa builder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/) by copying my published app link. It says that it could not find app manifest .

[image]

Comment: Please don't take pictures of text like errors or code. copy the actual text here.

Comment: @JamesZ Sorry!! I have added the actual error in the form of text now.

Comment: Can anyone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65870758/blazor-hosted-template-project-not-working-after-publishing-the-app) might help you (especially the comments)